# how can i pass a NSArray over WiFi network?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, networking, nsarray

can any one provide me a good way to send a NSArray object over wifi network.
 I have a code to sent a text message(string) over wifi network.
my code is

**Send**

```
- (void) sendText:(NSString *)string {
    const uint8_t *message = (const uint8_t *)[string UTF8String];


    if (_outStream && [_outStream hasSpaceAvailable])
        if([_outStream write:message maxLength:strlen((char *)message)] == -1)
            NSLog(@"Failed sending data to peer");
}
```

**Receiver Side**

```
- (void) stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{   
    switch(eventCode) {

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if (stream == _inStream) {
                // read it in
                unsigned int len = 0;
                len = [_inStream read:buf maxLength:buffSize];
                buf[len] = '\0';
                if(!len) {
                    if ([stream streamStatus] != NSStreamStatusAtEnd)
                        NSLog(@"Failed reading data from peer");
                } else {
                    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)buf];    }}
```

now the **message** contains my received message...
However i need to send a NSArray object over wifi.can any one help me to do it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `NSKeyedArchiver` to get a `NSData` object out of your `NSArray`, the `NSData` object is just a wrapper for binary data so you can send it over your socket. When you received the data, first transform it back into an `NSData` object and then use the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` class to get the array back.

Comment: And if you have custom objects in the array simply make their classes conform to NSCoding and implement the NSCoding methods. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need mechanism (protocol) that will send elements of array from sender end and in the same way it will receive at the reception end